# Can't run Appium on different machine

Tags: c#, selenium, npm, appium

I'm trying to run Appium server by following command:

```
appium --address 185.2.10.159 --port 4723
```

The address is another machine's IP (actually this computer is "sitting" next to me as well), and I have a Galaxy s5 connected there.
and I'm getting the following error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\x3686167>appium --address 185.10.2.159 --port 4723
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.1
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: '185.10.2.159'
[HTTP] Could not start REST http interface listener. Requested address is not av
ailable.
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 185.10.2.159:4723
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1237:19)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at net.js:1395:9
    at nextTickCallbackWith3Args (node.js:453:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:359:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this approach -

**Machine A:** The one you are using and which has all your code.
**Machine B:** The other machine where you have connected the phone.

---

On machine B, start the Appium server like this -

```
appium --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723
```

Please note, that the address mentioned above is not Machine B's IP. Its Appium server address.

---

Now, on machine A, you write your code by adding the machine B's IP -

```
driver = new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://185.2.10.159:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

The above code is Java, you can write equivalent c# code. **But the address mentioned above is Machine B's IP**

Answer (score 2):

> --address 185.10.2.159

This address is not machine's IP, its Appium server's address. This address should be localhost address in Appium. same should be used in your script.

Comment: What about running Appium on different machine and not locally?

Comment: try changing the ip address to the systems current IP address and change port to 4725 or something which is available and not already in use